# How to locally decrease the distance between an equation and its numerical label

Tags: equations, amsmath

I've faced with a situation like below in `IEEEconf` 2-column template:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, conference]{IEEEconf}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{My Title*}

\author{Guy$^{1}$
\thanks{*This work was not supported by any organization}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{$^{1}$Guy is with Hell, {\tt\small guy@hell.edu}}%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}

ABSTRACT

\end{abstract}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    \theta_{i}^{h^{-}} = \frac{\displaystyle 2(i-1)\pi}{\displaystyle m_{c}^{\hat{x}}}\\
    \theta_{i}^{h^{+}} = \frac{\displaystyle 2i\pi}{\displaystyle m_{c}^{\hat{x}}}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
    \theta_{j}^{v^{-}} = \frac{\displaystyle 2(j-1)\pi}{\displaystyle m_{c}^{\hat{v}}}\\
    \theta_{j}^{v^{+}} = \frac{\displaystyle 2j\pi}{\displaystyle m_{c}^{\hat{v}}}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

I'm gonna decrease the distance between right equation with its label (i.e. (3)), such that everything will be placed in a straight line.

**What is the best approach to do that?**

Update 1: result of @Zarko's code:

[image]

Comment: If you need it for a two-column format, then you should post a document in two-column format.

Comment: @gernot: The MWE is for two-column scenario, now.

Comment: since you're using `amsmath`, there is a command `\raisetag{,dimen>}` that can be applied if a tag is moved away from its "normal" position, which this one is.  try `\raisetag{1.5\baselineskip}` just before the second `\end{equation}`.  documented in `texdoc amsmath`, section 3.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation number has a minimum distance from the equation, but there's a slick trick in exercise 19.8 of the TeXbook.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, conference]{IEEEconf}  % Comment this line out if you need a4paper

\usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}

\title{My Title*}

\author{Guy$^{1}$
\thanks{*This work was not supported by any organization}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{$^{1}$Guy is with Hell, {\tt\small guy@hell.edu}}%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[2]\nopagebreak
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
    \theta_{i}^{h^{-}} = \dfrac{ 2(i-1)\pi}{ m_{c}^{\hat{x}}}\\
    \theta_{i}^{h^{+}} = \dfrac{ 2i\pi}{ m_{c}^{\hat{x}}}\\
\end{cases}
\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\hspace{.1\linewidth plus 4pt}%
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
    \theta_{j}^{v^{-}} = \dfrac{ 2(j-1)\pi}{ m_{c}^{\hat{v}}}\\
    \theta_{j}^{v^{+}} = \dfrac{ 2j\pi}{ m_{c}^{\hat{v}}}\\
\end{cases}
\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\nopagebreak\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}%
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

I have used `lipsum` to emulate some text before and after the equations. Note how to get the same spacing as for a normal `equation` environment, with no breaks before and after.

The trick is inserting a large glob of horizontal glue, which can be shrinked as much as possible:

```
\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
```

I have also reduced the width of the minipages, to avoid the left equation number to be too near to the part on the right.

Note also `\dfrac`, rather than all those `\displaystyle` tokens.

[image]

Comment: Still simpler than `\dfrac`: `dcases`.

Comment: It looks like the OP wants to typeset the numerators and denominators in display style. `\dfrac` doesn't quite achieve this: its numerators and denominators will be typeset in text style, not display style.

Comment: @egreg I like your font.

Comment: @Mico I disagree. There is no reason for using display style in the numerator and denominator here.

Comment: @toandhsp I don't. I just used the same as the OP.

Comment: I take it your disagreement is with the OP's typesetting objective and not with what I wrote. :-)

Comment: @Mico Compare the results. In my opinion, your's (and the OP's) is wrong: the exponents in the denominators are way too high.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with the improperly placed exponents in the denominators. Turns out it was caused by inappropriately sized math struts; I've updated the answer to correct this issue. After applying this correction, the difference between `\dfrac` and `\ddfrac` (the latter with typographic struts) is pretty much minimal...

Comment: @egreg You said there is a minimum distance between the equation and its number. Do you maybe know how much this distance is (in points per say)? Or if there is a command which gives this number?

Comment: @Jim It's basically 1em (in the symbol font, but usually this is the same as 1em in the text font).

Comment: @egreg Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*Edit:* Since the question was misleading, the first answer version was accommodate to one column document. Of course meanwhile, after editing of question, appears other answers ...

Reduce width of minipages and push them apart with `\hfill` and reduce space between equation and equation number by `\hspace{-1em}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

  \noindent$|$\hrulefill\ column width\ \hrulefill$|$

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth} % <-- reduced minipage width
\begin{equation}
  \begin{cases}
\theta_{i}^{h^{-}} = \frac{\displaystyle 2(i-1)\pi}{\displaystyle m_{c}^{\hat{x}}}\\
\theta_{i}^{h^{+}} = \frac{\displaystyle 2i\pi}{\displaystyle m_{c}^{\hat{x}}}
    \end{cases}\hspace{-1em}% <-- added to reduce distance to eq. numbering apart
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\hfill % <-- added to push minipages appart
\begin{minipage}{.48\linewidth} % <-- reduced minipage width
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
\theta_{j}^{v^{-}} = \frac{\displaystyle 2(j-1)\pi}{\displaystyle m_{c}^{\hat{v}}}\\
\theta_{j}^{v^{+}} = \frac{\displaystyle 2j\pi}{\displaystyle m_{c}^{\hat{v}}}
\end{cases}\hspace{-1em}% <-- added to reduce distance to eq. numbering
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I should have said that I am using this code in a 2-column environment in IEEEconf template. Your solution actually sent both labels to inappropriate position. Please find the update.

Comment: How do I know this? Please, in future be so kind and provide complete small document (MWE) not only code snippet ...

Comment: You are right. I do apologize due to wasting your time by that.

Answer (score 2):

Add some negative space

```
\begin{equation}
  \hspace{-2em}
  \begin{cases}
    ...
  \end{cases}
  \hspace{-2em}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt, conference]{IEEEconf}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{My Title*}

\author{Guy$^{1}$
\thanks{*This work was not supported by any organization}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{$^{1}$Guy is with Hell, {\tt\small guy@hell.edu}}%
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}

ABSTRACT

\end{abstract}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
  \hspace{-2em}
  \begin{cases}
    \theta_{i}^{h^{-}} = \frac{\displaystyle 2(i-1)\pi}{\displaystyle m_{c}^{\hat{x}}}\\
    \theta_{i}^{h^{+}} = \frac{\displaystyle 2i\pi}{\displaystyle m_{c}^{\hat{x}}}
  \end{cases}
  \hspace{-2em}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
  \hspace{-2em}
  \begin{cases}
    \theta_{j}^{v^{-}} = \frac{\displaystyle 2(j-1)\pi}{\displaystyle m_{c}^{\hat{v}}}\\
    \theta_{j}^{v^{+}} = \frac{\displaystyle 2j\pi}{\displaystyle m_{c}^{\hat{v}}}
  \end{cases}
  \hspace{-2em}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Updated the answer to employ the Times Roman `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` font packages instead of the somewhat obsolescent `mathptmx` package.)

By using the fairly recent `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` Times Roman font package instead of `mathptmx`, enough space is saved to let you use significantly narrower `minipage` environments -- providing more separation between the `minipage` environments

To simplify the code in the equations, the answer sets up a custom macro, called `\ddfrac`, which automatically typesets the numerator and denominator material in display style.

For extra legibility, you may also want to use (a) `dcases` environments instead of `cases` environments and (b) a few `\mathstrut` directives to increase the space between the fraction lines and the material in the respective denominators.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,conference,twocolumn]{IEEEconf}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}% not "mathptmx"
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\newcommand\ddfrac[2]{\dfrac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand\Tstrut{\smash[b]{\mathstrut}} % "top strut"
\begin{document}
\hrule %  just to illustrate width of text block
\section{INTRODUCTION}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{.45\columnwidth}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{dcases}
    \theta_{i}^{h^{-}} = \ddfrac{2(i-1)\pi}{m_{c}^{\Tstrut\hat{x}}}\\
    \theta_{i}^{h^{+}} = \ddfrac{2i\pi}{m_{c}^{\Tstrut\hat{x}}}\\
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\columnwidth}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{dcases}
    \theta_{j}^{v^{-}} = \ddfrac{2(j-1)\pi}{m_{c}^{\Tstrut\hat{v}}}\\
    \theta_{j}^{v^{+}} = \ddfrac{2j\pi}{m_{c}^{\Tstrut\hat{v}}}\\
\end{dcases}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```