# Is there a way to left align a simple equation without juggling spaces with hspace?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

Here’s an example of an equation I’m trying to align (I have lots throughout my 50-page NT paper):

```
$$\frac{5x^2}{4}+\frac{17x^4}{16}+\frac{65x^6}{64}+\frac{257x^8}{256}+\ldots \hspace{9.5cm}$$
```

**I want to be able to get rid of the hspace.**

It’d be really frustrating if all LaTeX has is this hspace thingy plus manual trial-and-error adjustments. And no, I don’t want to default left-alignment for all equations across the document, no.

Here’s my settings:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
```

Here’s the codes that are creating the centered formatting:

```
\[\frac{5x^2}{4}+\frac{17x^4}{16}+\frac{65x^6}{64}+\frac{257x^8}{256}+\ldots \]

\begin{flalign*}
\frac{5x^2}{4}+\frac{17x^4}{16}+\frac{65x^6}{64}+\frac{257x^8}{256}+\ldots 
\end{flalign*}
```

**I'm editing this question, so @egreg sees my code, which is not working to create equation numbering:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=15mm,left=15mm}

\newenvironment{eqleft*}
 {\begin{equation*}}
 {\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}\end{equation*}
\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
\begin{eqleft*}
\frac{5x^2}{4}+\frac{17x^4}{16}+\frac{65x^6}{64}+\frac{257x^8}{256}+\dotsb
\end{eqleft*}

\begin{ceqn}
\begin{align} \label{eq:eq:k_div_n_closed}
A=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\tan{\frac{2\pi nj}{k}} 
\end{align}
\end{ceqn}\\
\indent The above summation can be rewritten as a closed-form as follows:

\end{document}
```

**First issue**
[image: Second issue]

**Second issue**
[image: First issue]

Answer (score 3):

For a single left aligned equation (that is, not using `fleqn`), you can exploit `flalign*`, with *more* than one column.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[4]
\begin{flalign*}
\frac{5x^2}{4}+\frac{17x^4}{16}+\frac{65x^6}{64}+\frac{257x^8}{256}+\dotsb &&&
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `\dotsb` rather than `\ldots`.

Actually, you *can* do it with `\hspace` and no guessing:

```
\[
\frac{5x^2}{4}+\frac{17x^4}{16}+\frac{65x^6}{64}+\frac{257x^8}{256}+\dotsb
\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
\]
```

would do. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348745/4427

It's better, however, to define a proper environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newenvironment{eqleft}
 {\begin{equation*}}
 {\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}\end{equation*}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[4]
\begin{eqleft}
\frac{5x^2}{4}+\frac{17x^4}{16}+\frac{65x^6}{64}+\frac{257x^8}{256}+\dotsb
\end{eqleft}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

If you also want to be able to add equation numbers, define `eqleft` and `eqleft*`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newenvironment{eqleft}
 {\begin{equation}\hspace{0pt}}
 {\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}\end{equation}\ignorespacesafterend}
\newenvironment{eqleft*}
 {\begin{equation*}}
 {\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}\end{equation*}\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[4]
\begin{eqleft*}
\frac{5x^2}{4}+\frac{17x^4}{16}+\frac{65x^6}{64}+\frac{257x^8}{256}+\dotsb
\end{eqleft*}
\lipsum*[5]
\begin{eqleft}
\frac{5x^2}{4}+\frac{17x^4}{16}+\frac{65x^6}{64}+\frac{257x^8}{256}+\dotsb
\end{eqleft}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using that creates a problem, which is the equation numbers disapper. I want to replace begin{equation} with flalign but keep the equation numbers.

Comment: @JRS. Didn't I answer the question in the edit? Not with `equation`, of course, but this should not be a problem. Please, avoid comments in all caps or boldface.

Comment: Your new code to add equation number doesn't work

Comment: And the visual pollution of the latin texts doesn't help either.

Comment: @JRS. I see the expected equation number.

Comment: @JRS. I've just tried the code example from this answer: I get equation numbers. If you are not seeing them with this code, then I guess we need to see your `.log`  to see if there is a version issue. If you are not seeing them in your 'real' document, can you try to start from the demo and 'build up' until you can pin down the problematic part, so a suggestion can be made.

Comment: @egreg I've edited the OP to show my code, and I ran it, and it's not numbering the equation.

Comment: @JRS. You should notice that, in the final version `eqleft` numbers the equation, whereas `eqleft*` doesn't. If you use `eqleft*` it's obvious you don't get a number.

Comment: @egreg Yes, worked!

Comment: @egreg The only drawback is the fact the enhanced editor no longer displays the equations in green, as with the usual \begin{equation}. Is there a way to get that back?

Comment: @JRS. There are tens of “enhanced editors”.

Comment: @egreg Ok, thanks, I won't be too ambitious now, super happy I finally fixed that tough issue with your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code, it should produce the desired result

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}

\begin{document}

\[\frac{5x^2}{4}+\frac{17x^4}{16}+\frac{65x^6}{64}+\frac{257x^8}{256}+\ldots \]

\begin{flalign*}
\frac{5x^2}{4}+\frac{17x^4}{16}+\frac{65x^6}{64}+\frac{257x^8}{256}+\ldots 
\end{flalign*}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please explain your changes to the document by the OP (seemingly you only added `fleqn`)?

Comment: @Shashikr08 Hey