# Putting formula on the left side

Tags: luatex

Consider the following

\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}
    \begin{align}%
        \begin{split}%
            &\mathbb{P}_u(\tau^0=s, -R_{\tau^0}=z) =  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{u+s-z} \mathbb{P}( \tau^0>s-1, S_{s-1}=k)p_{u+s+z-k} \\
            & = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{u+s-z} p^{*(s-1)}_k p_{u+s+z-k}- \sum\limits_{k=u+1}^{u+s-z}  \sum\limits_{j=u+1}^{k} \frac{s-1+u-k}{s-1+u-j}p^{*(s-1+u-j)}_{k-j}   p^{*(j-u)}_j p_{u+s+z-k}
        \end{split}\nonumber
    \end{align}
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't you notice an `align` environment requires an ampersand at each line; to specify the alignment point?

Comment: You mean before =?

Comment: When I do that, formula in the second line is too big for the line. I only want to get the formula in the first line a little bit to the left.

Comment: Before whatever symbol you want to align, but most of the time, before `=`, `\leq`, `>`, &c.

Comment: Do you really need the default margins?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: The default margins are very wide, partly to hace space for marginal ,notes. If you don't use them, you can use the default of package `geometry`.

Comment: @Bernard But which margins are you talking about? In the align environment?

Comment: No the text margins. They're a bit smaller with the default geometry layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an effect like `\raggedright` you have to put the alignment character `&` at the first place of every line inside the `split` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}
    \begin{align}%
        \begin{split}%
            &\mathbb{P}_u(\tau^0=s, -R_{\tau^0}=z) =  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{u+s-z} \mathbb{P}( \tau^0>s-1, S_{s-1}=k)p_{u+s+z-k} \\
            & = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{u+s-z} p^{*(s-1)}_k p_{u+s+z-k}- \sum\limits_{k=u+1}^{u+s-z}  \sum\limits_{j=u+1}^{k} \frac{s-1+u-k}{s-1+u-j}p^{*(s-1+u-j)}_{k-j}   p^{*(j-u)}_j p_{u+s+z-k}
        \end{split}\nonumber
    \end{align}
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see:) I did not know that I can put & before any sign except =.

Comment: What does % do?

Comment: It's rather a good habit to put the comment sign `%` before a line break. This habit reduces the risk of having unwanted spaces in your output.

Comment: I see:) Perfect. Thank you very much:) You helped me a lot:)

Answer (score 3):

This uses a further line, because the final formula is very wide.

If your text width allows it, you can move left the alignment point in the first line and perhaps avoid the need to split the last formula.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}
\begin{equation}
\hspace{0pt}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\mathbb{P}_u(\tau^0=s&, -R_{\tau^0}=z)
=\sum_{k=0}^{u+s-z} \mathbb{P}( \tau^0>s-1, S_{s-1}=k)p_{u+s+z-k}
\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{u+s-z} p^{*(s-1)}_k p_{u+s+z-k}
\\
&\qquad-\sum_{k=u+1}^{u+s-z} \sum_{j=u+1}^{k} \frac{s-1+u-k}{s-1+u-j}p^{*(s-1+u-j)}_{k-j}
    p^{*(j-u)}_j p_{u+s+z-k}
\end{aligned}
\hspace{10000pt minus 1fil}
\end{equation}
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

I used a trick explained in exercise 19.8 of the text book. It's necessary to have a glob of zero glue at the beginning, in order that the alignment is flush left. The `\hspace{100000pt minus 1fil}` tricks TeX into thinking that the alignment is obnoxiously wide (but there is a lot of shrinkability to actually allow the typesetting).

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348745/4427

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your case I would consider the `multline*` math environment (defined by `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}
\begin{lem}
    \begin{multline*}
\mathbb{P}_u(\tau^0=s, -R_{\tau^0}=z) =  \sum\limits_{k=0}^{u+s-z} \mathbb{P}( \tau^0>s-1, S_{s-1}=k)p_{u+s+z-k}   \\
    = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{u+s-z} p^{*(s-1)}_k p_{u+s+z-k}-
      \sum\limits_{k=u+1}^{u+s-z} 
      \sum\limits_{j=u+1}^{k} \frac{s-1+u-k}{s-1+u-j}p^{*(s-1+u-j)}_{k-j}   p^{*(j-u)}_j p_{u+s+z-k}
    \end{multline*}
\end{lem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the advantage of multiline?

Comment: @Sarah, if you compare code, you should notice, that my answer have shorter code, not bother with ampersands. It is defined for such a cases as is yours, i.e for equation which you cant write in one line. It enable break it (manually) in two lines which are not aligned at left side.

Comment: Thank you for telling me:)

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `geometry` and `mathtools`, I propose these two variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}
\begin{multline} \mathbb{P}_u(\tau^0=s , -R_{\tau^0}=z) = \smash{\sum_{k=0}^{u+s-z}} \mathbb{P}( \tau^0>s-1, S_{s-1}=k)p_{u+s+z-k} \\ = \sum_{k=0}^{u+s-z} p^{*(s-1)}_k p_{u+s+z-k}-\!\! \sum_{k=u+1}^{u+s-z} \sum_{j=u+1}^{k} \frac{s-1+u-k}{s-1+u-j}p^{*(s-1+u-j)}_{k-j} p^{*(j-u)}_j p_{u+s+z-k}
\end{multline}
\end{lem}
\vskip2em

\begin{lem}$\mathbb{P}_u(\tau^0=s, -R_{\tau^0}=z) = \displaystyle\smash[b]{\smashoperator{\sum_{k=0}^{u+s-z}}} \mathbb{P}( \tau^0>s-1, S_{s-1}=k)p_{u+s+z-k}$
  \begin{equation} =\smashoperator{\sum_{k=0}^{u+s-z}} p^{*(s-1)}_k p_{u+s+z-k} -\!\! \sum_{k=u+1}^{u+s-z} \sum_{j=u+1}^{k} = \frac{s-1+u-k}{s-1+u-j}p^{*(s-1+u-j)}_{k-j} p^{*(j-u)}_j p_{u+s+z-k}
 \end{equation}
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what the geomtry and mathtools package does in this context?

Comment: Very gladly. `geometry` slighly increases the line width, since it uses smaller margins, which saves some space for the equation numbers, in case of long equations.

Comment: As to mathtools, I initially used it because I introduced a `multlined` environment inside  `equation`. This environment is not defined by `amsmath`, contrary to `aligned` or `gathered`, but I wasn't fully satisfied, so I didn't propose it. It also defines the `\smashoperator` command, which doesn't take into account the overflowing of the indices in the `sum` command, whence a better horizontal spacing – compare the spacing of the `=`  w.r.t. Σ at the beginning of the 2nd line in each version: only the 2nd version uses this command.

Comment: @Bernhard Very interesting. There is a lot I stillt have to learn. Thank you very much for your explanation:)